# UIbarbuttonitem appearance leads to crash

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

`CommonViewController`,which inherits from `UINavigationController`.i accomplish the following method in it.

```
+ (void)initialize{
    UINavigationBar *naVcBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    [naVcBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_nav"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];
    NSMutableDictionary *textAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [textAttributes setObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
    [buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

then,there is a `viewController` named `MovieListViewController`,which is `rootViewController` of that `CommonViewController`,the following is the code in it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *right=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"切换模式" style:(UIBarButtonItemStylePlain) target:self action:@selector(exchangeView)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=right;
}
```

the result is that the program crash.
it crashs at : `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=right;`

So i try to fix it and find that when i delete the code

```
UIBarButtonItem 
*buttonItem = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];
    NSMutableDictionary *textAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [textAttributes setObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
    [buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

everything is OK.
but i don't know the reason,why?thanks!

the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb048c3b3d0'

Comment: Where is the error message from xcode?

Comment: -[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb21162aa00

Comment: Can you post the whole message it cannot be it

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb048c3b3d0'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Put the error in your question instead of in the comments.

Comment: sorry,it's my first question,and my English is poor ,thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
[textAttributes setObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
```

You are passing in a color but specifying the "font" attribute. Change one of the two. Either pass in a font instead of a color or change the key to one used for a color.

Also, `UITextAttributeFont` is deprecated. Use `NSFontAttributeName` instead.